# How to achieve these modal overlay effects and geometry animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to figure how the website I'm going to show you is working. The parts I'm interested in are the video, the map and the contact modal. Can anybody show me where I can find the code or maybe a tutorial link or any help about how to achieve this?

http://maximize.com.br

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: "video, the map and the contact modal" - just that? It would take months or years of learning and practice to get to the point where you could write such a page, but I'm sure someone will condense it to a SO answer. "where I can find the code" right click, then View Page Source.

Comment: You're right, it is a very complex system. What I'm looking for is how technically these effects are created. Is that a SVG overlay or something else for starter.

Comment: The map is a [static jpeg](http://maximize.com.br/img/map.jpg). Most of the animations, including the showing of the contact form, are CSS transitions. I haven't noticed any videos.

Comment: Thanks Amadan. The video ins in the center of the page. I spent more time on it and they use png images for the triangles that they animates. I thought there were using svg technology which they don't.